# pdf of a simple random variable calculated two different ways.. with two different answers

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

so we have a random variable Y with a uniform pdf on the interval [0,1]. the question is, what is the pdf of W=Y^2.

method 1 using the transformation of variables formula:

$f_w=f_y(g^{-1}(y))\dfrac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)=\dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{w}}$

method 2 treating W like a product distriubtion of $Y*Y$ (
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution)

$f_w = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{|y|}f_y(w/y)f_y(y)dy = \int_w^1 \dfrac{1}{|y|}dy = -ln(w)$

both have similar cdfs. i don't know which is right or why i got different answers.

Comment: The first is right. The density function is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}}$ for $0\lt w\lt 1$, and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it another way. We find the cdf of $W$. For $0\lt w\lt 1$, we have $W\le w$ if and only if $Y^2\le w$ if and only if $Y\le \sqrt{w}$. But $\Pr(Y\le \sqrt{w})=\sqrt{w}$.

For the density, differentiate. We get $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}}$ on $(0,1)$, and $0$ elsewhere.

**Remark:** A problem with second approach is that it applies to a product of *statistically independent* random variables, which $Y$ and $Y$ are not.

Comment: The answer to the question asked is in the remark.

Answer (score 0):

The 'remark' above is on the right track, but has semantic ambiguities.

The OP is basically asking why is the pdf of $Y^2$ different to the pdf of $Y*Y$?

An easy way to think of the difference is: ... How would you simulate $Y^2$ vs the product of two independent $Y$ random variables?

- To generate $Y^2$, you would generate a SINGLE pseudorandom drawing of random variable $Y$, and then square it.
- To generate the product of two independent $Y$ random variables, you would generate TWO (different) pseudorandom drawings of $Y$, and obtain the product of them.

Comment: The remark in the other answer has no *semantic ambiguities*. // The notation $Y\ast Y$ is unusual when $Y$ is a random variable. A minima, it should be precisely defined, or, better still, carefully avoided.